# draging column averages from one sheet, vertically in the other excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have a survey sheet with the results of a huge questionnaire, each column is one question with the answers from respondents right underneath. Questions start from AW goes to VP in the survey sheet, and answers for each question are start from Row number 2 to 50,

Now in another sheet, I want to be able to drag a formula AVERAGE(Sheet1!AW:AW) in K1 down, by incrementing the columns from survey sheet, so the formula in the K2 to be AVERAGE(Sheet1!AX:AX)...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `INDEX` in your formula to reference a column in a range, and `ROW` to determine which column to get from the Index

Like This: (in `K1`, and drag down)

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Sheet1!$AW:$VP,,ROW()))
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, but doesn't calculate the average correctly with this formula.

Comment: Hi Basically in the sheet1 column AW I have these numbers starting from row 2 to row 50.  -> 3,5,5,3,2,5,5,4,4,2,4,4,3,4 of course some  in between some cells are empty because of no response to the question. The average I should get has to be 3.77 but I get 4 in K2, and dragging down also doesn't give me correct result. I tried the sum instead of average it didn't work either.

Comment: Ha just noticed your formula gives me average correctly but gets average starting from AZ rather than AW. so to get correct value for AW I used AT but, what could be the reason for this and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Could it be because I start from K4 to drag down skipping first 3 rows?

Comment: Sorted with =AVERAGE(INDEX(Sheet1!$AW:$VP,,ROW()-3))

Comment: Yes, you did say in your Q to put the formula in K1.  Glad you sorted it out